# Multiple blinking cursors in the same Form

Tags: codenameone

I have multiple blinking cursors in all TextFields, in the same Form. All of them are blinking, regardless the TextField in which I’m typing.

It happens in Simulator, Android, iOS and Javascript.

I’m not able to produce a test case: all my test cases are fine, this bugged behavior is only in my app, after changing the Form and the editable state.

Can you give me any hint to understand / investigate / solve this issue?

Thank you

Comment: There are some issues with the blinking animation, it's very finely tuned but possibly not tuned enough. It should only draw the cursor if the text field has focus so is it possible you manipulated focus in any way within the app?

Comment: Maybe. I didn't explicitly manipulated the focus using methods like `requestFocus()` or `setFocusable()`, however I removed the uneditable TextFields from a Container that has a leader Component to another Container in another Form that hasn't a leader Componet, and after that I made them editable. To do that manipulation, for each TextField I had to set `.getParent().setLeadCmp(null)`, otherwise I had a NullPointerException on tapping.

Comment: I found a proper solution to this issue, so I updated my answer.

Comment: Yes you can't change a lead component hierarchy or reuse elements from there. There are some assumptions about it. I'll need to think how to guard against that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated answer**

My old answer contained only a temporary workaround (`field.setCursorBlinkTimeOff(1000 * 3600);` for all `TextField`s) that has several issues that create a bad used experience.

Now I found a proper solution, that is simply to don't reuse the same `TextField`s *(removing that from a "Container A" that has a Leader Component and putting them in another "Container B" that hasn't a Leader Component)*. This issue is related to the fact that the "Container A" has a Leader Component.

So, in this case, my solution is to remove the TextFields from "Container A" and add new TextFields to "Container" B using a method like:

```
private Component replaceWithNewTextField(Component cmp) {
        if (cmp instanceof TextField) {
            // it creates the new TextField
            TextField field = new TextField();
            field.setUIID(cmp.getUIID());
            field.setText(((TextField) cmp).getText());
            field.setName(((TextField) cmp).getName());
            field.setEditable(((TextField) cmp).isEditable());
            ((TextArea) field).setSingleLineTextArea(((TextArea) cmp).isSingleLineTextArea());
            ((TextArea) field).setRows(((TextArea) cmp).getRows());
            ((TextArea) field).setConstraint(((TextArea) cmp).getConstraint());

            etc.
```